# Streaming opencv mat to flash player

Tags: flash, opencv, nginx, ffmpeg

I am looking for a way to programmatically stream opencv frames to a flash player (using RTMP). I am running nginx at the backend.

So far, I am able to find a way to stream flv file sitting on disk to flash player (note again programmatically): https://github.com/Akagi201/rtmp-push

I am also able to encode cv::Mat to AVFrame using libavcodec but I am not sure how can I encode push into RTMPPacket. Basically, I am not sure what should be the content of Data field of FLV tags. 
Refer:https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Does anyone know how bgr content of cv::Mat be converted to AVCVIDEOPACKET, explained on the above link?

Comment: **AVC** (Advanced Video Codec) is just another name for **H.264**. So encode  the openCV frame as H264 data (I don't use FFmpeg library code so I guess you find the option to set the AVFrame content to be of H264 format). Once you have a raw H.264 frame those bytes are the "content of Data field".

Comment: PS: Your question as it set is not answerable. It just doesn't work that way of converting BGR bitmapdata to FLV's AVCVIDEOPACKET. Is there any way to get OpenCV / FFmpeg to output (to disk) an FLV video containing your **cv::Mat** as single frame encoded via H.264? This would give you a starting point (correct bytes that you load from disk) cos after that you now have an FLV template containing the correct header, metadata & **AVCDecoderConfigurationRecord**.

Comment: From there onwards to add any further frames to the FLV you simply create an FLV video tag (AVCPAcket type 2 which can be **i-frame** or **b-frame** type). That means 11 bytes of tag header + an image encoded as AVC (BGR to H264 image) + 4 bytes of size (integer) for total SIZE (11+ H264 bytes length), this SIZE is called PreviousTagSize in the PDF.

Comment: Finally... the way I learnt was to get FFmpeg (from command line) to encode a single jpeg as FLV (with H264). Now also encode the Jpeg as just H264 only. Open that FLV in hex editor to see the bytes, and you should find the exact same h.264 file's bytes somewhere in the FLV version. This teaches you how to put what was previously H264 data inside an FLV. So now whenever you conver BGR to H264 you practice how to package it as an FLV video tag.